# Gaussian plume model in PostGIS or geocouch

Tags: postgis, model, gaussian-plume

Does anyone know of existing code for dispersion modeling using Gaussian Plume or comparable model, that I could plug in / adapt to be used programmatically from PostGIS or alternatively via GeoJSON/geocouch?

I'm trying to model something like this: http://ready.arl.noaa.gov/gaussian-bin/dispsrc.pl to calculate dispersion values providing as few inputs as reasonably possible: lat/lon, Wind Speed, Wind Direction (possibly cloud cover  maybe elevation, cloud cover, etc)

My primary objective is to return computed values for % concentrations at points A, B, C, D downwind from emission point X, assuming 100% at point of release X

Secondary objective is visualize it along the lines of something like below

[image]